I am trying to write code for x86 with assembly but the program says "process finished with exit code -11" without any input from me."
;nasm 2.10.09

section .data
  m_input db "write number", 0
  m_prompt db "symbol(+.-./.*)", 0
  m_invalid db "not symbol", 0
  m_output db "result", 0
  newline db 0x0A
  
section .bbs
  operation resb 4
  number1 resb 4
  number2 resb 4
  buffer resb 12
  result resb 4
  
section .text
  global _start

_start:
 
  mov eax, [m_input]
  call print_str
  call read_int
  mov [number1], eax
  
  mov eax, [m_prompt]
  call print_str
  call read_character
  mov [operation], eax
  
  mov eax, [m_input]
  call print_str
  call read_int
  mov [number2], eax
  
  
   mov al, [operation]
   cmp al, '+'
   je add_numbers
   cmp al, '-'
   je sub_numbers
   cmp al, '*'
   je mul_numbers
   cmp al, '/'
   je div_numbers
   
   mov eax, m_invalid
   call print_str
   call print_newline
   jmp exit
   
   
   
   
   
add_numbers:
  mov al, [number1]
  add al, [number2]
  mov [result], al
  
sub_numbers:
  mov al, [number1]
  sub al, [number2]
  mov [result], al
  
mul_numbers:
   mov al, [number1]
   mov bl, [number2]
   mul bl
   mov [result], al
   
div_numbers:
   mov al, [number1]
   mov bl, [number2]
   div bl
   mov [result], al
  
print_str:
   mov edx, [eax+4]
   mov ecx, eax
   mov ebx, 1
   mov eax, 4
   int 0x80
   ret
   
read_int:
   xor eax, eax
   xor ebx, ebx
   xor ecx, ecx
   xor edx, edx
   
   mov edx, 10
   mov ecx, [number1]
   mov ebx, 0
   mov eax, 3
   
   ;ascii table
   mov esi, [number1]
   xor ebx, ebx
   xor eax,eax
   
read_character:
  xor eax, eax
  xor ebx, ebx
  mov ecx, [operation]
  mov edx, 1
  mov eax, 3
  int 0x80
  ret
  
convert_loop:
  mov bl, [esi]
  cmp bl, 0x0A
  je e_convert
  sub bl, 0x30
  imul eax, eax, 10
  add eax, ebx
  inc esi
  jmp convert_loop
  
print_newline:
  mov eax, [newline]
  call print_str
  ret
  
e_convert:
  ret

print_int:
  mov ecx, 10
  mov edi, [buffer+12]
  
print_convert:
  xor edx, edx
  div ecx
  add dl, '0'
  dec edi
  mov [edi],dl
  test eax, eax
  jnz print_convert
  
  mov edx, buffer + 12
  mov edx, edi
  mov ecx, edi
  mov ebx, 1
  mov eax, 4
  int 0x80
  ret
  
exit:
   mov eax, 1
   mov ebx, 0
   int 0x80

I am trying to write code for x86 with assembly but the program says "process finished with exit code -11" without any input from me."
The error I get is "process finished with exit code -11" and I am writing via decoder
The entire code is above. I am just learning assembly language and I could not find the error in the code above. Thank you in advance for your help.

Start with small steps. You don't even print the first message properly. Also, learn to use a debugger.

See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for info on using a debugger and strace, and the rest of the wiki for some helpful links.
